# JavaScript gets effect by other script - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

I have a little problem. If I insert this code in the footer of my image, my sliders doens't work anymore...

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

This is caused by this code:

```
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

            <script>
            jQuery(function () {
                jQuery.widget("ui.tooltip", jQuery.ui.tooltip, {
                    options: {
                        content: function () {
                            return jQuery(this).prop('title');
                        }
                    }
                });

            jQuery(document).tooltip();

            });
            </script>
```

But why does it effect JavaScript and how can I fix that?

Kind regards

Comment: have you checked browser's console, are there any error message?

Comment: No, there aren't. Thats the point..